# How to wrap div element around newly typed text so that associated css result will be shown in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a simple text editor which shows the associated CSS results in real time. for example if a user clicks **Bold** Then text becomes bold while user is typing (it shows real time change). Same like this I want a button after click it will wrap the new text with a div tag with specified class or id.

I know wrap method can wrap the div or other tag. But after adding new div tags through wrap() I want store its result which contains newly added div tags. so that I can use those result to generate new html pages.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="texteditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" style="margin-top: 10px; height: 70%; text-align: center;">
        <h2><u>Simple Text Editor Created Using jQuery</u></h2>
        <div class="ze ie"></div>
        <style>
            .font-bold.bold {
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .italic {
                font-style: italic;
            }

            .selected {
                background-color: orange;
            }

            #openpb {
                margin: 15px;
            }
        </style>
        <button type="button" class="g-button g-button-submit" id='stext'>Text</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <button type="button" class="g-button g-button-submit" id='shtml'>HTML</button>
        <div id="controls" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <a id="bold" style="color: black; display: inline-block;" class="font-bold">
                <button type="button">B</button>
            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a id="italic" style="color: black !important; display: inline-block;" class="italic">
            <button type="button">I</button>
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a id="link" class="link" style="display: inline-block;">
            <button type="button">Link</button>
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select id="fonts" class="g-button">
            <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
            <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
            <option value="Monotype Corsiva">Monotype</option>
            <option value="Tahoma New">Tahoma</option>
            <option value="Times">Times</option>
            <option value="Trebuchet New">Trebuchet</option>
            <option value="Ubuntu">Ubuntu</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <iframe frameborder="0" id="textEditor" style="width: 500px; height: 80px; border: 2px solid #CCC; border-radius: 20px; overflow: auto;"></iframe>
        <textarea name="text" id='text' style="border-radius: 20px; overflow: auto; display: none; padding-left: 10px;" rows="6" cols="53"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is Jquery: as you can I have used setinterval method to show result in real time in textarea. same like this I want a button which will wrap new or selected text with div tag with specified id and class and I want store this changes(newly added div tag) in textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";
    document.getElementById('textEditor').contentWindow.document.close();
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    $("#bold").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
        boldIt();
    });
    $("#italic").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
        ItalicIt();
    });
    $("#fonts").on('change', function () {
        changeFont($("#fonts").val());
    });
    $("#link").click(function () {
        var urlp = prompt("What is the link:", "http://");
        url(urlp);
    });
    $("#stext").click(function () {
        $("#text").hide();
        $("#textEditor").show();
        $("#controls").show()
    });
    $("#shtml").on('click', function () {
        $("#text").css("display", "block");
        $("#textEditor").hide();
        $("#controls").hide();
    });
});
function boldIt() {
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("bold", false, "");
    edit.focus();
}
function ItalicIt() {
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("italic", false, "");
    edit.focus();
}
function changeFont(font) {
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("FontName", false, font);
    edit.focus();
}
function url(url) {
    var edit = document.getElementById("textEditor").contentWindow;
    edit.focus();
    edit.document.execCommand("Createlink", false, url);
    edit.focus();
}
setInterval(function () {
    var gyt = $("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html().match(/@/g);
    if ($("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html().match(/@/g) >= 0) { } else {
        $("#text").val($("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html());
    }
    $("#text").val($("#textEditor").contents().find("body").html());
}, 1000);
```

I don't want use third party text editor plugins. in short I want texteditor which contain a button, after clicking this button it will wrap new text with div tag with specified class or id. something like Stack Overflow text editor...with facility of adding custom div with specified class or id.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, I would suggest to use oninput instead of an interval.

Comment: how can i store the output of wrap show that i can show newly added text in textarea

Comment: can u give little example if possible for adding simple div tag through and showing its output in textarea

Comment: Well the output of wrap() is the return of wrap(). console.log($('<span>test</span>').wrap("<div class = 'test'>").parent().get(0).outerHTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #Problem{margin: 5px; outline: 1px dotted red; padding: 5px}
            #Solution{margin: 5px; outline: 1px dotted green; padding: 5px}

            #Solution textarea{
                height: 200px;
                width: 500px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            //Wraps the text in a new div with optional id and classname.
            //Returns the new div.
            function wrapMe(text, id, classname){
                var tE = null;

                if (text && text.trim() != ''){
                    tE = document.createElement('div');
                    tE.id = (id || '');
                    tE.className = (classname || '');
                    tE.innerHTML = (text || '');
                }

                return tE
            }

            //Adds the outer html of passed element to the textarea with a linebreak
            function addElementToTextarea(e){
                var tA = document.querySelector('textarea');
                if (tA && e){
                    tA.innerHTML = (tA.innerHTML || '') + e.outerHTML + '&#013;&#010'
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'Problem'>
            Problem: I don't want use third party text editor plugins. in short i want texteditor which contain a button, after clicking this button it will wrap new text with div tag with specified class or id. something like stackover flow text editor...with facility of adding custom div with speicifed class or id.
        </div>

        <div id = 'Solution'>
            <input type = 'text' />
            <button onclick = "addElementToTextarea(wrapMe(this.parentNode.querySelector('input').value, 'testid', 'testclass'))">Wrap me</button>
            <br /><br />
            <textarea readonly = 'readonly'></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to accept it if you have no further questions on it.

Comment: u mean to vote it up, i don't have that privilege yet

Comment: No, to accept it. So other people see the topic is closed and do not waste their time on something solved. Some green arrow next to the answer.

Comment: yes i just did it, kind of new here. Thanks :D @Lain